# Returning Unknown Type Without Generics

Tags: c#, generics

In my abstract base class `AbstractType`, I have an abstract auto-implemented property `Value` of unknown type. All my derived classes implement this property with their own types, such `string` or `double`. Normally, I know you would just make it `AbstractType<T>` and have the property be `T Value { ... }`. However, I don't have the ability to use generics in this case. In `AbstractType`, I'm trying to implement a method that returns a new derived class from `AbstractType`, so if I use generics, the caller has to know the type. If I make `Value` type `object`, then the caller has to wrap the object to the correct type - very inconvenient type/instance checking.

Here's what my class structure looks like (the method is simplified for the sake of demonstration):

```
abstract class AbstractType
{
    public abstract ??? Value { get; set; }

    AbstractType FromValue(int i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            return new NumberType();
        else
            return new StringType();
    }
}

class NumberType : AbstractType
{
    public override double Value { get; set; }
}

class StringType : AbstractType
{
    public override string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to do this without using generics?

Comment: Perhaps `dynamic`?

Comment: You say that if you use generics, the caller must know the type, but if you use `object`, the caller has to wrap the object to the correct type. Doesn't that mean that _regardless_ of what you choose, the caller has to know the type?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't. Thats exactly what generics are for. You will have to go with the object pattern.

Comment: @KennethK. That doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: @Servy I agree, but this question just doesn't make sense to me. "I can't use generics, but I can't use `object` either..."

Comment: @KennethK. Agreed, the question doesn't make sense.  That doesn't change the fact that you're proposing something that's no better than using `object`.  If the question doesn't make sense, then vote to close and ask clarifying questions if any come to mind, rather than proposing without understanding the question.

Comment: Well, I can use object, it just dirties everything up with casting, so I'd prefer not to use it, but I figured there would be no other way @KennethK.

Comment: It looks like you want your `Value` to be something like [IConvertible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) which most of the primitive types implement. You're still not offering much to your callers though.

Comment: You can have a look at [this](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/dotgnu-pnet/treecc/) old project that predates Generics. It looks similar to what you're doing and could produce c# output.